# How to encode html source code so that no one can see it on web. asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Hello i want to encode my html code, so that the user can't see it, how can i achieve this?

Example:

```
 <html>
    <head>
     </head>
     <body>
      </body>
 </html>
```

this is what i want

```
   xxxxxxsihsaidbasidbsadiashbdaisubdiuafjekfmefn
```

Comment: <sarcasm>Binary mark up language... Oh yes please !!!!</sarcasm>

Comment: unfortunately on web nothing is secure enough, specially the html if you truly wants to hide your web portal from everyone and if its a inhouse product . I suggest you create your own browser which internally pass the accessing systems local information and match that on server side. this is what we do in secure public sector projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this online tool to encrypt your HTML contents [Link](http://www.iwebtool.com/html_encrypter)

but keep in mind that will slightly slow down rendering performance. i used to do that many times when i was kid and realized that is not necessary at all

**if you're looking for an App use this [link](http://www.encrypt-html.com/download.htm)**

in addition. there are other tricky way to protect your media content as well.

***but please realize that smart minds can always read anything from your page :)**

Comment: this converts html to javascript?

Comment: Keep in mind that, while this will prevent View Source, it cannot stop a user from using a browser inspector to view the DOM.

Comment: @DallonF is there any complete safe way to do it?

Comment: unfortunately on web nothing is secure enough, specially the html if you truly wants to hide your web portal from everyone and if its a inhouse product . I suggest you create your own browser which internally pass the accessing systems local information and match that on server side. this is what we do in secure public sector projects.

Comment: @Alok Thank you for your wisdom, i will follow that path.

Comment: @Kirk Thank you, i am going to use the tool. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to hide the html from being read as it is rendered on client. Even if you send encrypted html you would need to convert it back to html so that browser renders it. The browsers are supposed to implement the html rendering as it is supposed to render.

If you receive the HTML on browser and converts to some encrypted string and display on browser even then the browser do not hide with you receive from the server. View the source of page would show the html you receive.

Comment: so.. it's not possible to tell the browser only what he need's to know(html etc) and show on source(ajsbdkasbd)?